# What's causing this drop in performance?

Tags: windows, performance, windows-explorer

So when browsing trough folders in Explorer, suddenly my mouse will stutter and scrolling trough folders goes extremely slow. This goes on for 10 seconds and happens multiple times a day. I don't see any peak in CPU or disk activity when this happens.

How can I identify what is causing this drop in performance?

Comment: Monitor your task manager for any processes that are taking up your CPU usage

Comment: I mentioned that in the question, there's no peak in CPU or disk activity when that happens.

Comment: Any Explorer extensions? Image previewer handlers?

Comment: do you use MSE? I saw such hangs when I've tried this tool in the past.

Comment: I don't have MSE. @surfasb, I believe not, I do have a lot of programs installed but no explorer extensions afaik.